# If I set `let x = document.getElementById("inputText").value` and update `x`, why doesn’t the value update?

Tags: javascript, reference

In the following example, why doesn’t the `value` property of the input with the ID `test` update to `"second"`?

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let test = document.getElementById("test").value;
  
  test = "second";
  console.log(test); // Logs "second", but input value is not updated.
});
```

```html
<label>Click on this test input: <input type="text" id="test" value="first"></label>
```

Comment: I get it, but can someone explain WHY you can set a reference to the object [document.getElementByID('test')]but not to the object's value [document.getElementByID('test').value]?

Comment: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_02.htm

Comment: "The basic rule in JavaScript is this: primitive types are manipulated by value, and reference types, as the name suggests, are manipulated by reference."

Comment: In the end, `document.getElementById().value` is a property. When you set a variable to what it returns, that's a copy of the value found in that property. Javascript does not give you the option of accessing a memory pointer/reference of that value.

Comment: Related: [If a variable is defined in terms of another, can it reflect changes in the binding of the other?](/q/42637782/4642212).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Javascript assigned x as a value and not a reference to the original object.

For example, you could instead:

```
function setText(x) {
    document.getElementById('test').value = x;
}

getText = function() {      
    return document.getElementById('test').value;
}
```

And the value you set with `setText()` will be reflected by `getText()`, since `getText()` will also use the reference object's value, and not a copy of the value.

**EDIT**

As Bryan points out, this would be a copy by reference with a global scope:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');

function setText(x) {
    test.value = x;
}

getText = function() {      
    return test.value;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLj2A/

The original `test` variable stores a reference to the element, not a value associated with an attribute of the element.

Comment: Aye, and you can store a reference here with `var test = document.getElementById("test")` and then doing something like `test.value = "second"`.

Comment: @Bryan - That's true, since you would be copying a reference to the `#test` DOM element. For purposes of the example and clarity, I chose to illustrate that directly. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are copying the value to a variable. Changing the variable won't change the original, because the variable just contains a copy.

If you store the reference of the element in the variable, you can use that to set the value:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.value = "second";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the element's value to a variable and then changing the variable. This is not reflected back in the element's value. You need to change the element's value instead.

```
document.getElementById('test').value = "second";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're setting the *value* of `test` to be the string `document.getElementById('test').value`.

You aren't linking the two together.

If you are looking to do that, you can use a function:

```
function test(x) {
  document.getElementById('test').value = x;
}

test('foo');
```

In Python, you can do this. In JavaScript, I don't think so.

Comment: The value is set here as the function `test`, not `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

because

```
document.getElementById('test').value
```

is a getter where as

```
document.getElementById('test').value = "second"
```

is a setter

Answer (score 0):

```
test = document.getElementById('test').value;
```

...only gives you a copy of the value at that instant. When you modify `test`, you need to put that back into input field you'd like to change:

```
var test_input = document.getElementById('test');
test_input.value = "second";
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the local variable `test` to "second" will do nothing.  I assume you want getText to update the DOM.  Try this:

```
 getText = function() { document.GetElementById('test').value("second"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Point to element instead of value: http://jsbin.com/axufi4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Although javascript ultimately treats everything as an object, I believe only arrays and objects are passed by reference. Strings, ints and floats are passed by value.

Text inputs will always give you a string (even if you restrict input to numbers)

Comment: Not even objects and arrays are passed *by* reference, they are passed *as* references. You can change the contents of the object, but you can't replace the object with another.

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is pass-by-value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    getText = function() {      
        var test = document.getElementById('test').value;
        test = "second";
        //note: if you insert "alert(test)" it returns "second"
        document.getElementById('test').value = test;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
document.getElementById('test').value = "second";
```

or

```
var el = dcument.getElementById('test');
el.value = "second";
```

As for why, I believe it has to do with something about Javascript being a "pass by reference" or "pass by value" language, on which subject there was a [very interesting discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-is-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) here on SO. (I'm not sure on this point, correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

because it's a string and is passed as value, not as reference. so the content of *value* is copied to *test*